# pgfplots: Numbers along the x-axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to recreate some Chromatograms (have the tab-separated data) but I need to get numbers along the x-axis with some vertical separation (lines/boxes) as can be seen below
[image]

The image was created with a software that ships with the chromatography system but produces rather ugly graphs/plots, I just need the numbers now.
Thanks!

Comment: What do the red numbers refer to? I can't work out how the scale is supposed to read.

Comment: The x-axis is volume (ml), the red numbers refer to fractions collected by the system. Fraction 1 goes from 0-4ml etc.
This is not exported by the software but that would be easy to write in oocalc/excel, question is how do I get pgfplots to draw it in similar fashion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `extra x ticks` option for this. You can supply a list of tick positions using `extra x ticks={<list>}`, and the corresponding labels using `extra x tick labels={<list>}`. The style of the extra ticks can be specified using `every extra x tick/.style={...}`. You can use all the options that are available for "normal" ticks, so you can set `x tick label as interval` to plot the labels between two tick marks, control the length using `major tick length` and the style of the tick marks using `every tick/.style`. The style of the labels can be set using `xticklabel style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:30, samples=100,xtick align=outside, enlarge x limits=false, enlarge y limits=upper,
    max space between ticks=40,
    extra x ticks={0,4,...,30},
    extra x tick labels={1,...,7},
    every extra x tick/.style={
        xtick align=inside,
         x tick label as interval=true,
        major tick length=5ex,
        every tick/.style={
            densely dashed,
            red,
        },
        xtick pos=left,
        xticklabel style={
            red,
            anchor=south
        }
    },
    xlabel=Volume / ml,
    after end axis/.code={
        \node  at (rel axis cs:1,0) [anchor=south west, align=left, red] {Sample\\number};
    } 
]   
\addplot [blue, thick] {(abs(x-18)<3)*(1+cos((x-18)*60))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a matter of interest, given Joseph's comments, I think this additional "axis", should be annotated, how would you recommend one does this?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I've edited my answer to show what I would do to label the extra ticks.

Comment: This is really great stuff - I will try to implement that. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

May be something along these lines could work (see below). It uses pgfplots after and axis code. This way you can use the axis coordinate system. `\foreach` is explained in the pgfmanual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
after end axis/.code={%
\foreach \x / \lab in {-4/1,-3/2,-2/3,-1/4,0/5,1/6,2/7,3/8,4/9}%
{\draw[red,dashed] (axis cs: \x,0) -- (axis cs: \x,5);%
\node[xshift=10pt] at (axis cs:\x,3) {\lab};}
}
]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]